# Mathematical relationships of three-phase motors

Tags: three-phase

I am developing an interface designed to calculate active, reactive and apparent power, power factor, capacitor value to be inserted (to make the correction) if necessary for FP = 0.95 and inform (in Δ or in Y). (Three-phase motor).

The system will input values ​​(measurements) using the two Wattmeter technique. So, on these four output variables, I calculated using some relationships. However, I don't know how to relate the value of the capacitor to these last two and identify, through calculations, whether it is a delta or Y type connection.

What I did

for active power
$$pt = w1 + w2 $$
For reactive power
$$qt = \sqrt(3) * (w2 - w1)$$
For power factor
$$\theta = tg^{-1}(qt / pt)$$
$$fp = cos(\theta)$$

So how do you calculate the other two variables, value of the capacitor to these last two and identify, through calculations, whether it is a delta or Y type connection?

Comment: What two variables do you refer to? Please write your title in English.

Comment: `identify, through calculations, whether it is a delta or Y type connection` I think that's impossible.

Comment: ok. then it would be the value of the capacitor for correction and the identification of the type of connection (delta or Y).